# Adding HTML property in C# when dealing with email

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio-2010, html

I am facing a situation where I need to process an incoming email which is in **plain text format** and then display the email as **virtual plain text**(Font Size =10.5 and Font type=Consolas) to the user.

My code till now

```
string Text = "<html><body><basefont size=3 font face= consolas>" + mailItem.HTMLBody + "</font></body></html>";
mailItem.HTMLBody = Text;
//Process the email and display
```

This works good, but during display this shows virtual plain text of **font size 10.0** instead of needed **10.5**. I tried changing the **basefont size to 4,5** etc. this does not change the display in any way.

**other options tried:**

1.Adding a CSS stylesheet. This will not work good as most email clients don't support it.

2.Adding a div tag to the code like this

```
string Text = "<html><div style=font-size:10.5px; font-face:consolas;>" + mailItem.HTMLBody + "</font></body></div></html>"
```

this also does not work.

My main objective is to display a virtual plain text email with Font Size 10.5 and font type Consolas to the user after the processing has been done.

Comment: Seems like your HTML formatting is a mess. No quotes for attributes, wrong closing tags, etc. Create html file with your text, then edit and view it in a browser (at least in 2 different ones), until desired result. Then paste decorating tags in program.

Comment: @Petr Abdulin I tried to add closing tags and quotes, but C# throes an error for new quotes..So I left the quotes as such..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach seems to be allright - you just have a `</font>` and a `</body>` too much + you should change "font-face" to "font-family". 
Also throw in double quotes - that will output one quote:

```
string Text = "<html><div style=""font-size:10.5px; font-family:Consolas;"">" + mailItem.HTMLBody + "</div></html>"
```